# ROS2 Synchronizer with ApproxTime policy: why there is no registerDropCallback to use a callback method with non synced messages?

Tags: ros, ros2

I have a class the does some processing on the information coming from two different messages, a point cloud and an image. I know how to use the `message_filters::Synchronizer` to grasp the two messages when they are considered *synchronized*. However, I would like to do some processing on the point cloud only, when the two incoming messages are not in sync.

In `ExactTime` policy based `Synchronizer`, it is possible to assign a callback in this case of dropped message, by assigning the callback function trough `registerDropCallback()`. Unfortunately, this method does not exist when creating a `Synchronizer` with `ApproximateTime` policy

Do you know if I can achieve the same result in case of `ApproximatePolicy`?

Thank you